# The meaning of "McWasp" in "Waspy McWasp"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In The O.C. Seth Cohen describes his mom's background as  "[Waspy McWasp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsten_Cohen)". What does "McWasp" mean in this context? Does it simply mean waspy? I found that "Mc" can mean generic or homogenized, but I am not sure if that's what it means in this case. Thank you.

Comment: OK, wasp is white Anglo-Saxon Protestant. Waspy means like one of those people. [I know, I am one. Ha ha] And Mc is used to criticize things as being similar to junk food as McDonalds. People build these AWFUL houses in the states, and some call them mc-houses. Dunno the spelling.

Answer (score 3):

The *Mc-* doesn't really have a deep meaning - it's just a flippant turn of phrase. (See [Boaty McBoatface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaty_McBoatface)). You could maybe interpret it as the character being a very good example of a given characteristic, or fitting it very well.

However, while Wikipedia does mention it, I think it's worth noting that "waspy" is [only remotely related to the animal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Anglo-Saxon_Protestants).

Answer (score 1):

In casual speech, to call someone or something *XXX McXXX* is to say that the person or thing is utterly described by 'XXX'. Seth's father is Jewish, and his mother is very much of a WASP background. The acronym means 'White Anglo-Saxon Protestant'. This form of sarcastic repetition reminds me of the Blackadder character saying that someone is (e.g.) 'Stupider than King Stupid of Stupidland'.

We British love our word play. The cable internet company Virgin Media has a practice of giving each of its vans a punning TV or movie related name. These include Claude Van Damme, Lee Van Cleef, Vangelina Jolie, and so on. One was called Van Diesel, but a story goes, had to be renamed because it had a gasoline engine and people kept putting the wrong fuel in it.

[image]